# Fill in a DropDownListFor with the Display tag in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, enums, helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to write a helper for my ASP.NET MVC3 website which will be able to return a new `SelectList` containing all the `Description` attribute tag of an Enum

For example, with the following enum :

```
public enum Test
{
    [Display(Name = "Membre 1")]
    Member1,

    [Display(Name = "Membre 2")]
    Member2
}
```

I would like to be able to fill a `DropDownListFor` with something like :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyTest, MyHelper(Test))
```

(with `MyTest` is a `Test` variable).

and I expect my `DropDownList` contains :

Membre 1

Membre 2

I used to use this working helper :

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type enumType = value.GetType();
    var enumValue = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
    MemberInfo member = enumType.GetMember(enumValue)[0];

    var attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
    var outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;

    if (((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).ResourceType != null)
    {
        outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
    }

    return outString;
}
```

... but I can't get it work in a `SelectList`

How can I modify this to directly "incorporate" it directly in my `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper ?

I have seen some helper over the Internet, especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705330/mvc-net-how-to-populate-dropdownlist-with-enum-values), but no one works for me. Does anyone is able to share a **short** and **elegant** helper which returns all the `Display` attributes of the members of an Enum in order to put them in a `DropDownListFor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what I use. It's a slightly modified version of something I found online at one point. I'd give credit where credit is due, but I don't remember where I found it originally at this point:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum enumeration)
{
    var list = (from Enum d in Enum.GetValues(enumeration.GetType())
                select new { Value = Enum.GetName(enumeration.GetType(), d), Text = d.GetDescription() }).ToList();

    var selectedValue = (int)Enum.Parse(enumeration.GetType(), Enum.GetName(enumeration.GetType(), enumeration));

    return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
}

public static string GetDescription(this Enum en)
{
    Type type = en.GetType();
    System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            return ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
    }

    return en.ToString();
}
```

In your view, you'd use it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyEnumProperty, Model.MyEnumProperty.ToSelectList())
```

Comment: I just try your answer because it was the first one. I creat you two methods in Tools\Helpers\AttributesHelperExtensions.cs, which is a static class where i've written some helpers. And in my view, `ToSelectList()` is not recognize... Is there some using or anything else I forgot ?

Comment: Sorry. You'll also need an `@using` directive at the top of your view pointing to your extension. Just like in anywhere else in your C# code, you have to let the compiler know where to find that method.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing  Enum type data, I think the easiest way is to use custom Enum helper and Templates. Below is how I implement them in my project.

1) Create Enum Helper

```
public static class EnumHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems(this Type enumType, int? selectedValue)
        {
            if (!typeof (Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enum");
            }
            string[] names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
            IEnumerable<int> values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<int>();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = names.Zip(values, (name, value) =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = GetName(enumType, name),
                    Value = value.ToString(),
                    Selected = value == selectedValue
                }
                );
            return items;
        }
        // Get Display Name
        private static string GetName(Type enumType, string name)
        {
            string result = name;
            DisplayAttribute attribute = enumType.GetField(name)
                .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                result = attribute.GetName();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string GetItemName(this Type enumType, int selectedValue)
        {
            if (!typeof (Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enum");
            }
            var itemName = GetName(enumType, Enum.GetNames(enumType)[selectedValue]);
            return itemName;
        }
    }
```

2) Create folder call "DisplayTemplates" in Shared folder.

3) Create View inside "DisplayTemmplates". The view will look like below:

```
@using Demo.Web.Helper
@{
    var itemName = typeof(Test).GetItemName((int)Model);
}
```

4) Create floder call "EditorTemplates" in Shared folder.

5) Create View inside "EditorTemplates". The view will look like below:

```
@using Demo.Web.Helper
@{
    var items = typeof (Test).GetItems((int?)Model);
}    
@Html.DropDownList("",items)
```

Here you have finished all of helper and templates, ready for use. When you want to implement Enum Type data, just use it like below:

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //
    public Test Test { get; set; } 
}
```

**View**

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Test)
 or
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Test)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what I was kind of looking for as well.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I really like your solution, but I have implemented Chris' solution, it is closest of what I've done and need less modification to put in my own project. However, I upvoted your answer ;-) Thanks again !